# Android: Passing same variable between 3 activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin, static

So I have a (Kotlin) data class that gets instantiated in my startup activity (we'll just call the object `dataObj`). I have two other activities that need access to the `dataObj` that was instantiated on startup. I know I could have my data class implement the `Serializable` interface so that I could pass the object between the three activities using intents. But I also have been thinking that I could use a static variable in the constructor so that I could easily just grab the values for the class. I'm just trying to figure out what is recommended and what is good practice.

Comment: What about a singleton?

Comment: Never used a singleton but that looks like a good option.

Comment: @tomerpacific that only works right/correctly if you save it to `onSaveInstanceState` in `BaseActivity` and restore it only once when app starts but `savedInstanceState != null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your use case, but I'd generally recommend against static implementations (to include singletons, see [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)). They become hard to test adequately over time and can (in short) lead to many other problems depending on implementation.

If it is a relatively simple object where state change is rare, only done in one Activity at a time, and/or irrelevant, implementing a `Parcelable` and passing that to each `Activity` via an `Intent` is probably best.

If this is a complex object or an object that can change dynamically, the preferable solution would be to use a dependency injection platform (such as Koin if you're using  Kotlin) to instantiate the data and provide it as a dependency. Koin is pretty straight forward, a very basic implementation from the Koin website (and missing just a few lines to be complete):

```
// Injected by constructor
class MyViewModel(val repo : MyRepository) : ViewModel()

// declared ViewModel using the viewModel keyword
val myModule : Module = module {
  viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) } 
  single { MyRepository() }
}

// Just get it
class MyActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

  // lazy inject MyViewModel
  val vm : MyViewModel by viewModel()
}
```

In this case, your object would be something like `MyRepository()` in the example. You'd just have to add the `startKoin([list of modules])` from there. If you wanted `MyRepository()` in your `Activity` you'd include it like `val myRepo: MyRepository by inject()`. I don't know if this is outside the scope of your project though, it all depends on what you're trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

One big issue with this is that static variables don't survive Android low-memory state, but sending intent between survives. Also read here about static variable. [(Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Comment: Technically they don't survive, but you CAN save them to `onSaveInstanceState` bundle, it's just that all activities need to do it, and should only be restored *once* (if app is starting but the first `savedInstanceState` is `!= null`).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. Send it via `Intent` after implementing `Serializable` or `Parcelable` by you data class,
2. Save your data object to `.txt` file and read it when you need it.

`static` it is not created for this kind of things and You shouldn't use it in this case.

In my opinion You should go with first option.

Comment: What about a singleton? I am beginning to think that a Singleton might be a good option (thanks tomerpacific)

Comment: that only works right/correctly if you save it to `onSaveInstanceState` in `BaseActivity` and restore it only once when app starts but `savedInstanceState != null`

Comment: You can use it also but the question is, is it not a overkill for Your needs?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best method (although there really isn't a perfect way to do this), but you could instantiate it in a custom Application class.

```
class App : Application() {

    val yourObject by lazy { YourObject() } //by lazy is useful if the Object needs to hold a Context or something that isn't immediately available

}
```

Add `android:name=".App"` to the `application` tag in your manifest so your App class is actually used. `.App` assumes it's in the root of your application package.

Then, from anywhere you have a reference to a Context, you can do something like:

```
(context.applicationContext as App).yourObject
```

to access the Object.